# Google Contacts API Failure - Server Down?

Tags: gdata, gdata-api, google-contacts-api, google-shared-contacts

All of a sudden I've found my Google contacts-integrated web app failing to make straightforward calls to the server.

I haven't changed a stitch of oAuth code in months but all of a sudden I can't connect or make calls on existing tokens.

The return is mostly garbage but in the header I'm getting a 401 - Unauthorized and in the body you have:

```
Error
401
(Client Error)!!1

That's an error.
There was an error in your request.
That's all we know.
```

I've since tried to run a few calls in the oAuth 2.0 Playground and experienced similar behaviour.  Any one else seeing this?

I've JUST seen this thread from a month ago:  [Google Contacts Data Api 401 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996957/google-contacts-data-api-401-error)

The docs have been restored however.

GOOGLE DEVS: Any insight on this matter is MUCH APPRECIATED ASAP.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. OAuth 1.0a in my case, but scope of https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ and accessing https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full (using OACurl to do so)

Comment: The Oauth2 playground is broken for me too, btw: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

Comment: Yep, confirm that it seems to be down us, and I can't make that request on the Oauth2 playground either.

Comment: Glad to see it's just not me.  This blows.  Need to work.

Comment: Looks like it's resolved for us now.